# should R-squared and adj.R-squared be the same in a linear regression model with single predictor?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, variance

I have run a model linear regression model with a single variable and the adj.R-squared is considerably lower than R-squared. As far as I know, adj. R-squared penalizes you for adding additional variables.

**Where does the difference come from if there is one single predictor in the regression?**

Comment: I recommend asking this over at [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That’s already answered here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/48703/what-is-the-adjusted-r-squared-formula-in-lm-in-r-and-how-should-it-be-interpret

Answer (score 0):

For `p` predictors

R^2_adj = 1 - (1-R^2)\frac{n-1}{n-p-1}

So for 1:

Adjusted R-Squared = ((R^2(n-1))-1)/(n-2)